# How to put auto width to floatingfigure?

Tags: floats, plot, width, wrap

I'm trying to wrap an generated graphic with text. But I cannot find what I have to put instead of `6cm` in `\begin{floatingfigure}[l]{6cm}` to let LaTeX designate correct width like it does with height.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{floatflt}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text

\begin{floatingfigure}[l]{6cm}
\psset{xunit=1.0cm,yunit=1.0cm,algebraic=true,dotstyle=o,dotsize=3pt
0,linewidth=0.8pt,arrowsize=3pt 2,arrowinset=0.25}
\begin{pspicture*}(-1,-1)(5,4)
\psaxes[labelFontSize=\scriptstyle,xAxis=true,yAxis=true,Dx=1,Dy=1,ticksize=-2pt 0,subticks=2]{->}(0,0)(-1,-1)(5,4)[AAA,140] [BBB,-40]
\begin{scriptsize}
\psdots[dotstyle=*,linecolor=blue](2.48,3.3)
\rput[bl](2.56,3.42){\blue{$A$}}
\end{scriptsize}
\end{pspicture*}
\end{floatingfigure}
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
\end{document}
```

Ouch, I have a new problem, if last text is too short and there's a new section or subsection following, text in new section overwrite graphic. There is solution for this or only should I avoid this kind of situations?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{floatflt}

\newsavebox{\floatbox}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text

\sbox{\floatbox}{%
\psset{xunit=1.0cm,yunit=1.0cm,algebraic=true,dotstyle=o,dotsize=3pt 0,
linewidth=0.8pt,arrowsize=3pt 2,arrowinset=0.25}
\begin{pspicture*}(-1.2,-1.2)(5,4)
\psaxes[labelFontSize=\scriptstyle,xAxis=true,yAxis=true,Dx=1,Dy=1,ticksize=-2pt 0,
subticks=2]{->}(0,0)(-1,-1)(5,4)[AAA,140] [BBB,-40]
\scriptsize
\psdots[dotstyle=*,linecolor=blue](2.48,3.3)
\rput[bl](2.56,3.42){\blue{$A$}}
\end{pspicture*}}

\begin{floatingfigure}[l]{1.1\wd\floatbox}
\usebox{\floatbox}
\end{floatingfigure}
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
\section{New section}
text text text
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). I took the liberty to format your post a little. See [this link for more details on available formatting](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/editing-help).

Comment: Wrapping text around a figure can be justified *only* if there's enough text to go past the figure. Leave such adjustments for the final revision of your document, when you're sure that the text won't change substantially.

Comment: Ok, it's just I'm trying to make the document indenpedent of paper size (A4 and Kindle's size mostly) and I began with latex a few days ago :).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can measure the box before using it:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{floatflt}

\newsavebox{\floatbox}

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
 text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text

\sbox{\floatbox}{%
  \psset{xunit=1.0cm,yunit=1.0cm,algebraic=true,dotstyle=o,dotsize=3pt 0,
    linewidth=0.8pt,arrowsize=3pt 2,arrowinset=0.25}
  \begin{pspicture*}(-1.2,-1.2)(5,4)
  \psaxes[labelFontSize=\scriptstyle,xAxis=true,yAxis=true,Dx=1,Dy=1,ticksize=-2pt 0,
    subticks=2]{->}(0,0)(-1,-1)(5,4)[AAA,140] [BBB,-40]
  \scriptsize
  \psdots[dotstyle=*,linecolor=blue](2.48,3.3)
  \rput[bl](2.56,3.42){\blue{$A$}}
\end{pspicture*}}

\begin{floatingfigure}[l]{1.1\wd\floatbox}
\usebox{\floatbox}
\end{floatingfigure}
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
\end{document}
```

I've made some changes to the body of the picture; for setting the width I used `1.1\wd\floatbox`, but also

```
\dimexpr\wd\floatbox+1em\relax
```

could be used to have a known clearance. The box bin `\floatbox` can be reused at will in the same way.

Comment: Perfect :), ty so much.